# Azure Maps Web - Wrong language

Tags: localization, azure-maps

I'm using Azure Maps web SDK, instantiating the map this way:

```
                map = new atlas.Map('map_canvas', {
                    authOptions: {
                        authType: 'subscriptionKey',
                        subscriptionKey: subscriptionKey
                    },
                    language: mLanguage
                });
```

The problem is the map is being translated in the required language only partially: e.g. tooltips are always in english and the same for the some traffic information.

I also tried setting the language this way:

```
atlas.setLanguage(mLanguage);
```

Nothing changed.
Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When it comes to languages, there are some limitations:

- Not all labels on the map will change to any supported language, especially road labels. Many place and road names have no translation in other languages. When it comes to mapping, road names typically won't be translated in regions for anything but the local native language. For example, if someone were visiting a place in real life, the street signs will not be translated to the users language, so at that level it is important that the map reflects what the user will see in real life when navigating around.
- Points of interest typically have limited translations available and come from a large number of providers. Localization support is limited for these.
- Most tooltips (aria labels) are localized in the map control.
- Traffic data is collected from a large number of sources and typically only available in the local language for the area the data is relevant to.